# Why algorithm2e doesn't make new line for line end with "\;"?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

I already add "\;" in the end, why they are still in the same line? I am using algorithm2e package.

```
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \While{H is not empty}{
            u := deletemin(H)\;
            \For{all edges (u,v) in E}{
                \eIf{dist(v) > dist(u) + l(u,v)}{
                    dist(v):=dist(u)+l(u,v) \;
                    prev(v):=u\;
                    decreasekey(H,v)\;
                }
            }
        } 
\end{algorithm}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you add your code as a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, your code results in proper linebreaks on my system. Two comments: the `>` character should be typeset in math mode (`$>$`), otherwise it will show as an upside-down question mark `¿`. Also: for an `if` without `else` you can use `\If{condition}{statements}` instead of `\eIf`.

Comment: I agree with Marijn, I cannot reproduce your output on my system. Though I had an error due to the missing `{}` at the end of `\eIf`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP¨did not provide a MWE and the issue cannot be reproduced when making one.